# Expressing irony and sarcasm

Tags: грамматика

How would you translate sarcastic phrases like "oh yeah, that would be GREAT" in reaction to unwanted advances?

Answer (score 3):

Similarly: with an exaggerated affirmation (both in wording and in tone). And likewise, the sarcasm will usually be detectable only in the context.

> Ну да, конечно!
>
> Разумеется, вот прямо сейчас!
>
> Прекрасно, просто прекрасно!

etc.

Comment: and first example is also a target for joke about how two positives can make a negative.